# Automatic daily checks in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get requests from users.
The goal is to process them as soon as possible.
An initial estimated time of 5 days is added to the start date, within which the request will be processed.
I would like to make sure that if the estimated time has not been respected and make an update in the status of the request.
I have no idea what to use and how to do it.
I created a command, that everyMinute "it should" work but nothing.
If i use the command with terminal it work goods!

Kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
    '\App\Console\Commands\CheckDateEnd',
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();

    $schedule->command('CheckDateEnd:checkDateEnd')
        ->everyMinute();
}

protected function commands()
{
    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

CheckDateEnd.php

```
protected $signature = 'CheckDateEnd:checkDateEnd';

protected $description = 'Termine stimati verificati!';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    \DB::table('richieste')
        ->whereDate('termine_stimato','<=',Carbon::now())
    ->update(['stato' => 3]);

    $this->info('Termine stimati verificati!');
}
```

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: I don't understand your question completely, but "daily" in PHP / Laravel often asks for cronjobs. Or in Laravel's case [scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) which is also triggered by cronjobs.

Answer (score -1):

you can use jobs or scheduled task in laravel

scheduled taks:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    //your command
})->daily();
```

jobs are a little bit more complicated but more flexible because you can call the queue also on controllers

documentation:

- [scheduled task](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)
- [jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#creating-jobs)

for starting the scheduled task just call

```
php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run
```

but it would be better to install a crontab on linux/unix systems

```
crontab -e
```

add

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: What's in the errorlog?

- \DB::table('richieste') -> don't you have a model for this?
- where('termine_stimato','<=',Carbon::now())

Comment: Yes now i changed it,,,\App\Richesta:whereDate(...)
If i use the command into terminal work good!
Other tips?
I don't see error...

Comment: how do you call the scheduled task? via crontab?
is the task really running? perhaps add $this->info("Start CheckDateEnd:".Carbon::now); & $this->info("End CheckDateEnd:".Carbon::now);

Comment: The format it's correct, Carbon::now() give me the correct hour.
I prepare just the kernel.php and CheckDateEnd.php
Sinceraly, i don't know how to call the scheduled task....